# Rewrite Condition with Special Case for Homepage

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I switch my Business from one Domainname to another and want to use a 301 Redirect/Rewrite to keep the Google Ranking.

The special case is, that the Startpage and One other Page should go to a new Subpage on the new Domain, everything else should stay the same because of the structure of the new Domain is the same like the old one.

I tried several kinds of RegExp and another order. Maybe I misunderstand the path to a solution completly.

Maybe I should do a simple 301 Redirect on the Old Webpage and try to look into the referer on the New Apache Configuration and make an internal rewrite to /catvilla/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.co.nz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/oldname/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.co.nz/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/oldname/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.co.nz/pricelist/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/oldpricelist/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.co.nz/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The Apache Config in my VirtualHost right now, redirect everyging to www.new.co.nz/oldname all the time, eben for example for http://www.old.co.nz/webcam, what should go to www.new.co.nz/webcam.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

So far I see the following is working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/oldname/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pricelist/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/oldpricelist/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.co.nz/$1 [L,R=301]
```